# How to chain blocks of calculations and transformations on a dataset in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-design

I've been a database developer for many years across many p[latforms, but this is my first heavy work in Oracle.  I've been trying to figure out how to move a set of structures from SQL Server to Oracle for a week now and every path seems to end in a wall.

In SQL Server, I have a query that takes a set of records and does some light calculation and then pivots the results to a temp table where a second query takes the temp table and does some fairly involved calculations and re-grouping of the columns. These procedures are wrapped in a third query that calls the second one with different sets of parameters (user entered) to build a block of data for a graphing package.

So, the question is -- what is "best practice" for such a chain in Oracle?

The people here that use Oracle said the "proper approach" is to build a table and put the data in to the table and then pass that along. Surely this is wrong - I can't believe I have to build and maintain a database of empty tables to hold intermediate results of various calculations.

I thought `sys_refcursor` was perfect and built the first query that way (I didn't care for the SQL having to be built as a string and then executed, but I could live with it).  But when I went to the second query, I couldn't load/manipulate the `sys_refcursor` as a table, but had to loop through assigning each of the values to a variable and then, after the calculation, re-concatenate the values in to a `sys_refcursor` to pass to the next step. Surely this is wrong.

I finally conceded that I could live with some table objects that I would initiate as needed and then discard on completion. But now I can't find any material that would point to late instantiation. It seems that I still have to build the table separately and leave it out in the structures as an artifact.

So - what's the best approach in Oracle for chaining blocks of calculations and transformations on a dataset together? Am I just not finding the right documentation? Or am I going down the wrong paths?  Or do I need to treat Oracle as a procedural language and just load the data to an array (can you build an array?) and then, when I'm done, push it back to a `sys_refcursor` for release to the calling program.

Comment: When the people there said to pass along a table, might they have meant [a PL/SQL collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#sthref348)? Those are sometimes referred to as PL/SQL tables... Storing transitory data to a permanent table would add a lot of overhead and be slower.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  But as best I can see, they really mean "make a table."  I don't have much insight in to the databases they've worked on - I hope I'm misunderstanding.  But once again, I'm concerned that the words they use don't mean what I think they do.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to implement ETL processes in PL/SQL.

`pipeline table function` are the closest to what you wrote - [this is a good tutorial](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions.php).

you can also use `dbms_scheduler` ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm)) to create a chain of actions.

But personally, i'm more of a *keep is simple stupid* kynda guy so my advice to you is to write a simple package in pl/sql.

books you might find useful

[Oracle® Database Data Warehousing Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/toc.htm)

[PL/SQL Language Reference - Tuning PL/SQL Applications for Performance](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/tuning.htm#i48876)

Comment: <grin> I've already got all the complexity I need.  I'm with you on the "KISS" approach.  I'll give those books a look.
Thanks